# How to override drawing order for CALayers when parenting

Tags: ios, drawing, core-animation, calayer

I'm in a bit of a conundrum.  I'd like to stack CALayers in a certain order to draw one over the other, but I'd also like to benefit from the inherited transforms that parenting those layers brings.

Imagine a body, upper arm, forearm, and hand.  I'd like to set the anchor points and parent for arm and hand so I can rotate the arm and the hand will follow.

Here's what I do:

```
CALayer *body = [CALayer layer];
body.path = @"body.png";
body.anchorPoint = ap1;
CALayer *arm = [CALayer layer];
arm.path = @"arm.png";
arm.anchorPoint = ap2;
CALayer *hand = [CALayer layer];
hand.path = @"hand.png";
hand.anchorPoint = ap3;
[myView.layer addSublayer:body];
[myView.layer addSublayer:arm];
[myView.layer addSublayer:hand];
hand.parent = arm;
arm.parent = body;
```

All well and good, but what if I want the body to overlap the arm and hand?  Is there a way to keep this parenting order but override the drawing order?  Any clever ideas for doing this?

Comment: Have you tried adding the body last? When you add a sublayer it is placed on top of everything. Since you added the body first it is placed and then the arm and hand are placed above it.

Comment: Regardless of the order I add sublayers, the "arm.parent = body" line will put the body layer below the arm layer. It seems parenting requires this sort of layer ordering. I was hoping to find a way to still benefit from the transformational hierarchy while overriding drawing order somehow -- perhaps in a clever subclass of the containing view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sublayers always draw in front of their superlayers. You can't change that.

Siblings (sublayers of the same superlayer) can use the `zPosition` property to get finer grained control of the rendering order. By the way, there are some performance implications of having a lot of sublayers, so I'd switch to a more graphics focused framework before you get way too many `CALayer`s going.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I've done quite a bit of work this way already and it's been fine except for this ordering issue, which has cropped up only from time to time. What options are you suggesting by "more graphics focused framework"?

Comment: Quartz 2D would be an obvious choice, but wouldn't have the parent/child relationships you're relying on. Beyond that, its possible a game-focused graphics library (not from Apple) would be a good fit. At some point, using UIKit to do complex graphics is probably going to stop working for you. It is really designed for user interface elements.

Comment: Thanks, Adam, I do appreciate it.  I'd upvote, but it takes 15 reputation points.